# Como otimizar conexão Java com Postgres

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, hibernate, conexão

Minha classe de conexão com o banco de dados está demorando muito para abrir a conexão, demora quase uns 20 segundos.
Uso Hibernate e o Banco é o Postgres rodando localhost.

Estou fazendo algo de forma errada? ou da pra otimizar e abrir mais rapido?

Minha classe:

```
  public class Connection {

    private static final String UNIT_NAME = "NameConection";
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    private EntityManager em = null;
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (emf == null) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String user = ConfiguracoesFile.getInstancia().getUsuario();
            String pass = ConfiguracoesFile.getInstancia().getSenha();
            String banco = ConfiguracoesFile.getInstancia().getBanco();
            String server = ConfiguracoesFile.getInstancia().getServidor();
            String porta = ConfiguracoesFile.getInstancia().getPorta();
            map.put("hibernate.connection.password", pass);
            map.put("hibernate.connection.username", user);
            map.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://" + server + ":" + porta + "/" + banco);
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(UNIT_NAME, map);
        }
        return em;
    }

}
```

É normal demorar  uns 20 segundos para abrir em localhost?

EDIT:

Consegui melhorar um pouco o tempo de carregamento usando as  propriedades

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
```

Mas ainda esta demorando quase 10 segundos para  abrir a conexão.

Existe alguma outra propriedade que pode estar  incorreta e por isso está demorando?

Comment: Tenta definir esta propriedade: `map.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults","false");
`. [Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075081/hibernate-slow-to-acquire-postgres-connection)

Comment: Me retorna esta exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set